# Create an array of footprints in KiCad

Tags: kicad

I want to create a 16x16 LED array in KiCad and I would like to minimize any "manual" work. I can easily copy/paste in schema editor but I would like to align the footprints on PCB in a grid.

I did find these options so far:

1. Assign the footprints manually. This is the worst case, I will have 512 footprints and even with the use of grids etc, it is a long and error prone work. Not to mention that I may need to do it all again when I decide to change i.e. the grid spacing
2. Python scripting. This seems like a reasonable way, for example as in [KiCAD parametric component placement](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/452966/kicad-parametric-component-placement/453580#453580) . But still I will need to make the traces.
3. Skidl - this seems to be more complicated than scripting inside pcbnew and it even does not allow for footprint placement afaik...
4. The array tool - this will distribute one component and make copies so I would need to manually redo all references and create traces
5. Copy/paste - this seems like the most viable method, but I will still need to redo all references.

Comment: Reference designators should get sorted out automatically, they just might not be in an order you like.  I'd probably do it in code though.  Hopefully this is surface mount, otherwise it's going to be insane to assemble.  Are you sure you can't buy suitable LED arrays and make it up out of 8x8 blocks or something?

Comment: Yes, it will be SMD. The whole point is to see cost difference if we ordered it assembled by jlcpcb (or other vendors) vs using whole panles (where we have a vendor). The difference is that we may need to add some other parts to the board and it could be better than creating separate "control board" for each panel. I just thought that it will be few minutes in KiCad, send it to jlcpcb page to estimate the cost and done. However it turned to be to not so easy and it stuck in my head and I keep thinking that there must be some easy way that I just do not see :-)

Comment: For ballpark quoting purposes it probably doest matter if your traces are right or reference designators in any human sensible order.  You could just connect all the anodes to a pour on one side and all the cathodes the other then throw some representative control logic along the edge.

Comment: You are right and that is how I did it in the end. But I get "obsessed" with it and I would like to know if I am missing some obvious way.... And if we decide to go with it I would like to have the most efficient way how to do it because I know for sure that we will change the parameters of the grid at least 5 times :-)